# How to update a view whilst a function is being executed?

Tags: swift, object, uiview

I'm building a A* pathfinding algorithm in swift.
I've got this point object that represents each point on the grid

```
/// Point Object for each node in the grid
class Point {
    var gridCoordinate: [Int]
    var fCost: Double
    var gCost: Double
    var hCost: Double
    var neighbors: [Point] = []
    var parent: Point?
    var isWall: Bool
    var cell: UIView = UIView()


    init(x: Int, y: Int, f: Double, g: Double, h: Double, neighbors: [Point]) {
        self.gridCoordinate = [x, y]
        self.fCost = f
        self.gCost = g
        self.hCost = h
        self.neighbors = neighbors
        self.parent = nil
        self.isWall = false
    }



    /// Shows the Object on the main view
    func showPoint(on view: UIView, withTheColor color: UIColor) {
        let width = view.frame.width / CGFloat(cols)

        // Seting up the UIView
        cell = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(gridCoordinate[0]) * width, y: CGFloat(gridCoordinate[1]) * width, width: width, height: width))

        // Seting up the UIView

        cell.backgroundColor = color
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.3
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        view.addSubview(cell)

    }


    /// Finds all the neighbors of a givin Point Object
    func findAllNeighbors(grid: [Point]) {

        var results: [[Int]] = []

        let lowerBoundOfXRange = gridCoordinate[0] - 1
        let upperBoundOfXRange = gridCoordinate[0] + 1

        let lowerBoundOfYRange = gridCoordinate[1] - 1
        let upperBoundOfYRange = gridCoordinate[1] + 1


        for xCoordinate in lowerBoundOfXRange...upperBoundOfXRange {
            for yCoordinate in lowerBoundOfYRange...upperBoundOfYRange {
                if xCoordinate < 0 || yCoordinate < 0 || xCoordinate > rows - 1 || yCoordinate > cols - 1 {
                    continue
                } else if xCoordinate == gridCoordinate[0] && yCoordinate == gridCoordinate[1] {
                    continue
                } else {
                    if gridCoordinate[0] - 1 == xCoordinate && gridCoordinate[1] - 1 == yCoordinate {
                        continue
                    } else if gridCoordinate[0] + 1 == xCoordinate && gridCoordinate[1] - 1 == yCoordinate {
                        continue
                    } else if gridCoordinate[0] - 1 == xCoordinate && gridCoordinate[1] + 1 == yCoordinate {
                        continue
                    } else if gridCoordinate[0] + 1 == xCoordinate && gridCoordinate[1] + 1 == yCoordinate {
                        continue
                    } else {
                        results.append([xCoordinate, yCoordinate])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for i in results  {
            for item in grid {
                if item.gridCoordinate == i {
                    neighbors.append(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have an array called grid that holds all the Point objects.
There is a function called 'main()' that runs the algorithm.

In my view controller I have an UIButton called 'startButton' that when pressed starts the algorithm but only evaluates one node every time it is called.

```
while openSet.count > 0 {
    main()
    for item in cloedSet {
        item.showPoint(on: view, withTheColor: .red)
    }
}
```

The openSet is all the nodes that are going to be evaluated and the closedSet are all the nodes that have been evaluated. So when there are no more nodes to be evaluated then there is either a path and it will show it or there is not.

I would like to show the process of it evaluating each node. Turn each cell red when it has been evaluated.
So I modified it so it would wait one second then does it again.

```
while openSet.count > 0 {
    main()
    for item in cloedSet {
        item.showPoint(on: view, withTheColor: .red)
    }
    sleep(1)
}
```

But when I run it that does't happen it waits but doesn't update the view.
It waits for it to be complete before showing updating the view.

How do I make it so it will show the process as it's evaluating each node.
Thank you.

Comment: Never use `sleep(_:)` on main thread

Comment: What should I instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Robert says, never use sleep on the main thread. It freezes your app's UI.

Instead, start a timer that fires once a second and invokes your code each time it fires (either a selector or the more modern version that takes a closure.)

In the timer code, add a new item from your set. You'll need an instance variable to keep track of the items you've added. (If your collections openSet and closedSet are `Set` objects you might need to map the original set to any array so you get a consistent order when you iterate through them.

Comment: I'm sort of new to swift, how would I set a timer that fires once a second?

Comment: @TitanSwift `Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in }`

Comment: Note that UI updates don't actually take effect until your code returns and the app visits the event loop. Thus your wait wouldn't work in any case.